# Can you be buried with tzedokoh receipts?

Tags: death, tzedakah-charity, funeral-burial-levaya

When you pass away can you request to get buried with your tzedokoh receipts? Will the burial people allow it?

Is it worth it, I know everything gets recorded by God, but I've heard stories of people asking to be buried with things. Do you take the stuff with you when you go upstairs?

Comment: Your mitzvot have been recorded in the Book. Why would you need to be buried with your tzedokah receipts? What makes you think physical things matter? Does G-d not know you did the mitzvah of tzedokah?

Comment: That's kind of the flip side of the question, why do people sometimes ask to be buried with holy objects or writings

Comment: Actually, the opposite is true: your family should keep it.  Hashem knows what mitzvot you did.  The IRS does not and might want proof.

Comment: Sounds Egyptian/pagan.

Comment: what would be the purpose of being buried with something?

Comment: @dude There are stories of judgement time upstairs where they place the weight of the physical items on the scale and it gets tipped for the good. Which brings up a secondary question, would a lot of receipts of smaller donations be better than fewer receipts of larger donations?